# PyTorch create combination of ranges

Tags: python, pytorch

Is there a way to nest `arange`'s easily to create all the combinations of two ranges in PyTorch? For example:

```
x = torch.arange(2, 4)
y = torch.arange(0, 3)

something(x, y)
# should be [[2,0], [2,1], [2,3], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2]]
```

I.e., something with the same functionality as this python code:

```
l = []
for x in range(2, 4):
   for y in range(0, 3):
       l.append([x, y])
```

where the `range(x,y)` we can change.

Comment: Should the result be a list or a pytorch tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately there's a built-in function that does what you need and it is the `torch.cartesian_prod()` function.

Here's an example:

```
x = torch.arange(2, 4)
y = torch.arange(0, 3)
l = torch.cartesian_prod(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
x = torch.arange(2, 4)
y = torch.arange(0, 3)

m,n = len(x),len(y)
res = torch.stack([
    x[:,None].broadcast_to(m,n),
    y.broadcast_to(m,n)]
    ).permute(1,2,0).reshape([m*n,2])
```

Result:

```
tensor([[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2]])
```